# File writing in python failure

Tags: python, file, input, pygame, output

I am having a small problem with file writing a high score in a simple endless tunnel racer type game.

Itll write the high score if before I start the game, nothing is in the file. But after there IS a number in the file, it completely ignores the:

```
if score > hs:
    hs = score
    hsfile = open("hs.txt", "w")
    hsfile.write(str(hs))
    hsfile.close()
```

To open the file and check if something is written I have the code:

```
hf = open("hs.txt", "r")

h = hf.readline()

if len(h) > 0:
    hs = h 
else:
    hs = 0
```

Restatement:

If nothing is written in hs.txt, the highscore is added upon to and then written into the txt file.

If something is written (after 1st play and restart of application), the score stays as what is written in the file. Help?

Full code if needed:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random

pygame.init()

disw = 640
dish = 480

white = (255,255,255)
black = (  0,  0,  0)
brown = (193,125, 58)
green = (  0,220,  0)

gameExit = False

score = 0

speed = -2

spawned = False

hf = open("hs.txt", "r")

h = hf.readline()

if len(h) > 0:
    hs = h 
else:
    hs = 0

if gameExit == True:
    h.close()

rockx = 640

rocky = random.randint(0, dish)

rockw = random.randint(10,150)

rockh = random.randint(10,150)

ship = pygame.image.load("ship.png")

bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")

gameOver = False

def rock(thingx,thingy,thingw,thingh,color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def rockhit():
    global score, spawned, speed, rockx, rocky, rockw, rockh
    rockx = 640
    rocky = random.randint(0, dish)
    rockw = random.randint(10,150)
    rockh = random.randint(10,150)
    score += 1
    spawned = False
    speed -= 1

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y 
        self.w = w 
        self.h = h

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((disw,dish))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tunnel")
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def main():
    global gameOver, score, spawned, speed, rockx, rocky, rockw, rockh, hs, gameExit
    shipdimensions = Ship(200, 10, 60, 40)
    xc = 0
    yc = 0
    def startGame():
        gameDisplay.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        gameDisplay.blit(ship, (shipdimensions.x, shipdimensions.y))

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    yc = -6
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    yc = 6
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    if gameOver == True:
                        startGame()
                        gameOver = False
                        speed = -2

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    yc = 0

        shipdimensions.y += yc
        rockx += speed  

        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        gameDisplay.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        gameDisplay.blit(ship, (shipdimensions.x, shipdimensions.y))

        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
        text = font.render("Score: " + str(score), True, green)
        gameDisplay.blit(text, (1,1))

        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
        text = font.render("High Score: " + str(hs), True, green)
        gameDisplay.blit(text, (1,20))

        if gameOver == True:
            font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
            text = font.render("Game Over, press 'Space' to restart.", True, green)
            gameDisplay.blit(text, (100,200))

        if shipdimensions.y < rocky + rockh:
            if shipdimensions.y + shipdimensions.h < rocky:
                pass    
            elif shipdimensions.x > rockx and shipdimensions.x < rockx + rockw or shipdimensions.x + shipdimensions.w > rockx and shipdimensions.x + shipdimensions.w < rockx + rockw:              
                rockx = 640
                rocky = random.randint(0, dish)
                rockw = random.randint(10,150)
                rockh = random.randint(10,150)
                speed = 0
                gameOver = True
                score = 0

        if gameOver == False and spawned == False:
            rock(rockx,rocky,rockw,rockh,brown)

        if shipdimensions.y <= 0:
            shipdimensions.y = 0

        if shipdimensions.y + shipdimensions.h >= dish:
            shipdimensions.y = dish - shipdimensions.h

        if rockx <= 0:
            rockhit()

        if score > hs:
            hs = score
            hsfile = open("hs.txt", "w")
            hsfile.write(str(hs))
            hsfile.close()


        pygame.display.update()
        Clock.tick(60)

if '__main__' == __name__:
    main()
```

Comment: Note that this code is never executed: `if gameExit == True: h.close()` since you set `gameExit` to `False` earlier in the program. And to actually close your file you need `hf.close()`. And yes, if you open a file with `'r'` you need to close it before you re-open it with `'w'`.

Comment: gameExit = False when I exit the game, it is run before closing. It works now with someone elses' fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting the hs to an int when you read it (otherwise it'll be a string)?

```
if len(h) > 0:
    hs = int(h)
else:
    hs = 0
```

e.g. you get weirdness comparing strings and ints.. viz:

```
>>> 12 > "10"
False
```

in the python interpreter.  (Python should probably throw an Exception. I can't think of a time when you'd want to compare an int and a string).

Comment: Thanks, it worked, there is a small bug I think I can fix on my own with it.

Comment: Yup, fixed the bug where it wrote out each number, thanks for the answer! can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to close hf before opening the same file for writing.

Comment: Did not work! I think it has something to do with that if and else statement at the top, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in read and write mode? use "r+" instead of "r" or "w" so you only have to deal with opening the file one time

Comment: Same error doing that, i am confused on why this is happening